Can we take the inner product of state vectors prepared in separate disjoint Hilbert spaces?
Sounds trivial yes at first, but reading the reply to post presented here by ecterrab 14085 confused me. I'm trying to understand the theoretical foundation behind comparing quantum states prepared independently in separate labs. Suppose Alice and Bob each prepare a single-qubit state, $|\psi\rangle_A$ in Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_A$ and $|\phi\rangle_B$ in Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_B$.

Is it meaningful or mathematically valid to take the inner product
$\langle \psi_A | \phi_B \rangle$ when these vectors belong to
disjoint Hilbert spaces?
If not, what adjustments or frameworks allow such comparisons,
especially in scenarios where states are compared or matched against
a target in quantum competitions?
How do practical settings (e.g.,experimental setups or judging panels in competitions) handle this comparison? Are these states embedded into a shared space or combined in some other way?

I've seen references to operations within tensor product spaces and embedding states into larger composite systems. However, I am seeking a more concrete explanation or references that discuss this problem, both in theory and practical applications.

I'm not an expert in the subject so won't post a full answer, but the way I see it is that, in your specific case, $\mathcal{H}_A$ and $\mathcal{H}_B$ are isomorphic, so you can "map" the vectors from one space to the other without the need of any transformation, and compare them using the inner product that the spaces share. I don't see any issues with this.

@diemilio On physics exchange I found same question in different context and the reply to it is not a simple yes or no. Maybe you or others can understand it https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/437038/how-is-it-possible-to-take-the-inner-product-of-states-which-belong-to-two-diffe

Is it that Hilbert space dimensions have to match to take inner product? but then again how can we take inner product of a 3 level qutrit (3^m) with 2 level system qubit (2^n)? Since for what integer n,m>0 3^m=2^n

Well, that is why I said that my answer was for "your specific case" where you were trying to compare two objects that belong to isomorphic spaces. If you want to make comparisons between objects of spaces that have different dimensions (but are induced by the same inner product), my guess is that you can use an isometric embedding to map objects from one space to the other, but I don't want to comment more on this since, as I said, I don't feel qualified to give a full answer without the risk of making mistakes.

A Hilbert space is not a physical thing, it is a mathematical object. So if they are both states of a single qubit, then they both live in the same Hilbert space (that of a single qubit). What is different between Alice’s and Bob’s states is that they are states of two different qubits. It is perfectly sensible to calculate the mathematical object $\langle \psi_A|\psi_B\rangle$ as long as the states live in the same Hilbert space, which in this case you asserted that they do. If they live in different Hilbert spaces, then the inner product is not defined.
As for physical interpretation, it is the same as if they are two states of the same qubit: amplitude of one state in the other. The magnitude squared of that gives the probability of obtaining one state if the other is measured in a basis containing the first. If Alice and Bob can get together and coherently interact their qubits, then they can estimate that probability using e.g. a swap test. Any other physical interpretation you like for amplitudes also applies. Hope this helps!
